# Combining year month days columns to form index for a time series data in R

Tags: r, time-series, tidyverse

I have a rain fall data as a tibble read from excel file. Its formatted like

| Year-Month | Day1 | Day2 | Day3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2020-01 | 0.5 | 0.6 | 0.8 |
| 2020-02 | 0 | 0 | 1.5 |
| 2020-03 | 5.2 | 1.0 | 10.5 |

I need it to be in the following format so as to perform time series forecasting of in R.

| DATE | RAINFALL |
| --- | --- |
| 2020-01-01 | 0.5 |
| 2020-01-02 | 0.6 |
| 2020-01-03 | 0.8 |

The DATE column has to be of the date and the RAINFALL column should hold the value of the rainfall of a particular day of a year.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reshape from 'wide' to 'long' with `pivot_longer`, `unite` the 'YEAR', 'Day' columns to create 'DATE' column and then convert the type to `Date` class with `ymd` from `lubridate`

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(lubridate)
df1 %>% 
    pivot_longer(cols = -YEAR, names_to = 'Day', 
       names_prefix = 'Day', values_to = 'RAINFALL') %>%
    unite(DATE, YEAR, Day, sep= '-') %>%
    mutate(DATE = ymd(DATE))
```

-output

```
# A tibble: 60 x 2
   DATE       RAINFALL
   <date>        <dbl>
 1 1901-01-01      2.7
 2 1901-01-02      0.4
 3 1901-01-03      4.7
 4 1901-01-04     10  
 5 1901-01-05     13  
 6 1901-01-06     16.9
 7 1901-01-07     19.2
 8 1901-01-08     18.3
 9 1901-01-09     15.7
10 1901-01-10     10.6
# … with 50 more rows
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(YEAR = c("1901-01", "1902-02", "1903-03", "1904-04", 
"1905-05"), Day1 = c(2.7, 4.1, 3.8, 3, 1.7), Day2 = c(0.4, 3.2, 
5.9, 4.6, 4), Day3 = c(4.7, 7.5, 7.6, 5.5, 7.4), Day4 = c(10, 
10.3, 7.1, 10.3, 9.3), Day5 = c(13, 10, 12.9, 13.6, 11.9), Day6 = c(16.9, 
15.1, 14.9, 16.3, 16.5), Day7 = c(19.2, 18.2, 17.6, 20.2, 20), 
    Day8 = c(18.3, 17.4, 17.3, 18.5, 17.6), Day9 = c(15.7, 15, 
    15.5, 13.9, 14.7), Day10 = c(10.6, 10.2, 12.1, 11.2, 8.4), 
    Day11 = c(4.9, 6.3, 6.9, 5.4, 5.5), Day12 = c(3.5, 3.5, 2.7, 
    4.8, 3.8)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -5L))
```